# remove ' string from a number

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to remove the ' sign from the net_amount, vat_amount and gross_amount.
How can I do that without removing the " . " sign?

```
net_amount  vat_amount  gross_amount
  '0.950000  '0.0732         1
   103        '8.2          null
```

The logic would be if there is a ' sign, then remove it and keep the numbers with the comma,
if not, keep the original number.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to correctly input floats in your dataset in first place?

Comment: This looks like an error in excel in which the leading `'` is used to force data as string, better ensure that this software produces a correct dataset in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic syntax for the replace() method.

```
str.replace(old_str, new_str[, optional_max])
```

The `old_str` parameter represents the substring you want to replace.

The `new_str` parameter represents the new substring you want to use.

The `optional_max` parameter represents the maximum count of times to replace the old substring with the new substring.

The return value for the `replace()` method will be a copy of the original string with the old substring replaced with the new substring.

**in your case**

```
print(net_amount.replace("'", ""))
```